# How do I make peer successfully without no rule to make target in fabric

Tags: makefile, hyperledger-fabric

When I am trying to make peer through Makefile, there reports an error, it shows :

> "no rule to make target "./build/bin/peer" need by peer.Stop.

And I find that there is nothing generated in the `.build/bin` directory. I don't know what happened. Please help me.
My fabric is 1.4

Comment: What command you use to make?

Comment: I use the "make peer" command. After I know that it is due to the lack of dependency, I can successfully run it by adding the missing tools according to the error message. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Last week the team released Hyperledger Fabric version 2.4.1., bringing some substantial improvements to the programming model for Gateway client applications and smart contracts (Chaincode as a Service).  If possible, please consider upgrading to the latest release, or a modern 2.x build - in addition to the latest feature updates the build toolchain will generally be stable.

Comment: I'm realizing the work of others, so I have to use the old version. Thank you for your answer.